# is there any easy way to drag and drop cells from table to table?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to pick random cells from one table to another by drag and drop , is there any library to do this?? using javascript and php.

And i need to save the cell id in database for future use.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: have a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/Rusln/fwjaj/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya you can do it with jqueryesay ui

see this example

http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/dd/dnd3.php.

To save the cell id , you can use array push and store it to database.